# Devise Confirmation Resend "Login can't be blank" error & Confirmation link from email has "Confirmation token is invalid" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

ruby '1.9.3'

"rails", "3.2.13"

"devise", '~> 3.2.2'

I'm using the Devise confirmation controller without modification. I create a user and the email is sent. Then clicking on the link to confirm results in "Confirmation token is invalid". The token in the email is the same as in the database.

Also when the user is in Registrations edit I provided a link to resend the confirmation email. This brings the user to Confirmations New and you fill in the email and click the "Resend Confirmation instructions" button and receive the error "Login can't be blank." The user is logged in, otherwise they would not be able to get to users/edit or users/confirmation/new.

I have configured devise to accept a user_name or email for login.

Comment: Do you mean that the confirmation token in the url is identical to the confirmation_token column in the database for that user?  Also, there is no need for a user to be logged in to get to users/confirmations/new.  Un-logged-in users can resend confirmation emails by default.

Comment: Correct they are identical. I understand there should be no need to sign in for the confirmations/new .
Email:
<a href="http://localhost:5000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=716276a13f8200b2e79e9c84c9b6ce9a718018dda37752525b27af6958300176" target="_blank">Confirm my account</a>

Database:
users.confirmation_token = 716276a13f8200b2e79e9c84c9b6ce9a718018dda37752525b27af6958300176

Comment: In devise 3.1, the original token is inserted in the default email template (if you use it) and an encrypted version is stored in the db, so they shouldn't be the same (except for tokens in the db that were generated before you upgraded devise if you're using `config.allow_insecure_token_lookup`).  It looks like that token in the link you posted is an encrypted form rather than the original token.  Have you overridden the confirmation email template?  If so, you need to use `@token` which is passed into the template by devise, instead of `@resource.confirmation_token`.

Comment: I am using the @token. This is what has me confounded.  <%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token) %>

Comment: That's weird.  That's the same url I'm using in my overridden email template and it's fine.  Have you overridden the devise mailer or anything in confirmable or the devise token generator?  Sorry; I have to ask!

Answer (score 0):

During password reset ensure resent_password_sent_at column against user record must be set to  Time.now /time when particular password change token is being sent.

```
raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(@user.class, :reset_password_token)
@user.update_attributes(reset_password_token: enc, reset_password_sent_at: Time.now)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My issue is with the email confirmation process. When the user clicks the "confirm my account" link an error occurs "Confirmation token is invalid"

Comment: Yup, that's only. even you set the token still how devise will recognize it as a latest token or an old one, hence we need to update the rest_password_sent_at flag to current time(or the time when the token was sent).. which can be treated as a available token !