# Confirmation token is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Devise 3.2.2.  And turned on Confirmable.

With SQL, it shows a successful token is created in the users table.

And the token is in the email link that's generated. But clicking on it, gives a Confirmation token is invalid error.  I already having working code to allow for login using username or email, but hope that is not conflicting.

ERB:

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  # Virtual attribute for authenticating by either username or email
  # This is in addition to a real persisted field like 'username'
  attr_accessor :login

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :approved, :role, :username, :userfriendlyname, :persona, :public, :login, :active, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at  
  # attr_accessible :title, :body



  # MTM 06/21/2014 to allow for login with username or email
  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end

    # MTM 06/23/2014 to allow for login with username or email
  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
  where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I read through a lot of other similar questions on SO, and this one helped at least understand the flow, since the user was in a similar bind.
[Devise Confirmation Resend "Login can't be blank" error & Confirmation link from email has "Confirmation token is invalid" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067170/devise-confirmation-resend-login-cant-be-blank-error-confirmation-link-from)

But I got my solution to work with the following things.

Step 1.

confirmation_instructions.html.erb was originally created when I was using a pre Devise 3.1.x version, so the link_to code had changed. There are many articles in SO on this.

essentially, replacing :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token with :confirmation_token => @token.

Step 2.

This was the tricky part.  I had created a custom mailer earlier which is working fine, and so there had to copy over the Devise actions into the custom mailer.  Again, maybe because I was using an older version of Devise at the time, there was no mention of @token in these actions, so added a @token = token, in the confirmation_instructions action/method, since token is passed into this action/method as a parameter.

```
  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    @token = token    
    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions)
  end
```

By doing so, and by looking at the Rails console as I submitted a resend of confirmation instructions request, I could see what the other SO articles were talking about regarding typical Devise 3.1 and higher behavior, which is, the a confirmation_token is created and stored in the database, but it IS NOT the same value sent with the confirmation instructions email, which seems to be an encrypted version.  When I click on the email link, it went to the login page and said the confirmation was successful.

Answer (score -2):

Change this code with you code and check.

**%p= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource)**